# 301 redirect to modified url from .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, hosting

How to make redirect 301 from ulr: https://domen.com/some-word/* to https://domen.com/products/some-word/* using .htaccess

make 301 redirect from one url to another

```
RewriteEngine on
# RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
# RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

how i can to resolve this problem?

Comment: I assume the `*` signifies any-URL and this should be redirected to the same URL at the target? eg. `/some-word/foo` to `/products/some-word/foo`?

Answer (score 1):

Requests that start with `/some-word/` can be matched and redirected with `RewriteRule` (as @MrWhite suggested) that prepends the `/products` to `%{REQUEST_URI}`:

```pascal
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^some-word/ /products%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Make sure to put this at the **top** of your `.htaccess`, otherwise it might not work because of the other rules.

Comment: There's no need for the additional _condition_ (`RewriteCond` directive) here. The check for `/some-word/` should be in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ instead. eg. `RewriteRule ^some-word/ /products%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` (note the absence of the slash prefix on the URL-path that is matched). @Serhii

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I've edit the answer to use this simplification.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use mod_rewrite for such a redirect (unless perhaps you are already using mod_rewrite for other rules). A simple mod_alias `Redirect` directive would suffice.

For example:

```
Redirect 301 /some-word/ /products/some-word/
```

The `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target. So, `/some-word/foo` would be redirected to `/products/some-word/foo` by the above rule.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect